# How do you reload a component in react

Tags: reactjs

I'm using a component from a third-party library, so I have no way to modify it. The components internally maintain their own state (uncontrolled components).

I want to reload this component at a certain point (e.g. when the user clicks) to restore its internal state to its initial value.

That's what I'm doing right now, but the `reload` function doesn't seem very elegant to me. Is there a better solution?

> `<Child></Child>` represents the third-party library component and internally maintains a count. When the user clicks the reload button I'm going to reload `<Child></Child>` so that the `count` inside `<Child></Child>` goes back to `9`.

```js
const Child = function Child() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(9)

  const increment = () => {
    setCount(count + 1)
  }

  return <>
    <div>
      <div>{count}</div>
      <button onClick={increment}>+</button>
    </div>
  </>
}

const Parent = function Parent() {
  const [flag, setFlag] = useState(true)

  const reload = () => {
    setFlag(false)
    setTimeout(() => {
      setFlag(true)
    })
  }

  return <>
    <div>
      <button onClick={reload}>reload</button>
      {flag && <Child></Child>}
    </div>
  </>
}
```

Comment: Everything is explained in the docs: [Preserving and Resetting State](https://react.dev/learn/preserving-and-resetting-state#)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trigger child re-rendering in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30034265/trigger-child-re-rendering-in-react-js)

Comment: long story short - you need to give your component, that u wish to reset the state, a `key` prop and change it to something different each time to want it to reset the state.

Comment: @Arkellys This document solves that problem, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way you can perform a re-render is using by changing the key prop that can be passed to the child, simply incrementing the key will do the trick.

`const [keyValue, setKeyValue] = useState(0)`

`<Child key={keyValue} />`

If you are going to attach this to a button to re-render it, simply do:

`<button onClick(() => {setKeyValue(keyValue => keyValue + 1)})></button>`

Refer to the official documentation [Resetting state at the same position](https://react.dev/learn/preserving-and-resetting-state#resetting-state-at-the-same-position)